# Add a terms and conditions checkbox in Woocommerce registration form

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, registration

In woocommerce registration form, there's no "terms and conditions" before sign up button.

Is there a way to make it appears in the form?

Here is [the link of my theme layout](https://woodmart.xtemos.com/my-account/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Updated on july 2018 - Added compatibility for Woocommerce version 3.4+

If not done yet, first you need enable terms and conditions on checkout page:

1. To create a new page in Wordpress for your terms and conditions
2. To enable that page in Woocommerce > Settings > Checkout > Checkout pages *(section)*: 
   [image]
3. Then save… you are done.

---

The code to get the term and conditions check box on registration form:

```
// Add term and conditions check box on registration form
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_terms_and_conditions_to_registration', 20 );
function add_terms_and_conditions_to_registration() {

    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'terms' ) > 0 && is_account_page() ) {
        ?>
        <p class="form-row terms wc-terms-and-conditions">
            <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_terms_is_checked_default', isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ), true ); ?> id="terms" /> <span><?php printf( __( 'I&rsquo;ve read and accept the <a href="%s" target="_blank" class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-link">terms &amp; conditions</a>', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'terms' ) ) ); ?></span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1" />
        </p>
    <?php
    }
}

// Validate required term and conditions check box
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'terms_and_conditions_validation', 20, 3 );
function terms_and_conditions_validation( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['terms'] ) )
        $validation_errors->add( 'terms_error', __( 'Terms and condition are not checked!', 'woocommerce' ) );

    return $validation_errors;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

When checkbox is not ticked, an error message is displayed.

[image]

> This checkbox is only a validation step (It is not saved in database, as we don't use that information anywhere).

---

### Addition:

To allow terms and conditions **only in Registration page** use one of the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_show_terms', '__return_false' );
```

Or

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_terms_and_conditions_checkbox_text', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested on WC 3.5+ and works.

Comment: I tried to save the code and an error occurred in line 22.syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file

Comment: Hi, does it save into the wp_user table that the user accepted the terms?

Comment: @retroriff None of the terms and conditions are saved… They are just used for mandatory customer acceptance (here or in checkout)…

Comment: This would do the trick in order to EU GDPR Compliance:

`function woocommerce_privacy_policy_save( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['terms'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'privacy_policy', $_POST['terms'] );
}`

Comment: @retroriff In which table in database is stored the user acceptance?

Comment: @retroriff is not stored, is just used for validation

Comment: @retroriff Sorry but in this answer code, this user acceptance **is not stored** in database… It's just used for validation…

Comment: @LoicTheAztecYes,  I know. My snippet stores it to accomplish EU GDPR Compliance.

Comment: @retroriff Note: The new WooCommerce 3.4 introduce and manage EU GDPR Compliance.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That's right. The new WooCommerce 3.4 don't allow to register or checkout users that don't accept terms and conditions. Therefore I guess that we don't need to save their acceptances in the database anymore.

Comment: @Pbinder I would like to save a checkbox if the user wants to receive emails or not. Which action should I use to save that value in the database?