# Add Terms & Conditions Checkbox On Registration Only And NOT on Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There's a solution on adding a terms & conditions checkbox on registration page as seen here [Add a terms and conditions checkbox in Woocommerce registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311826/add-a-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-in-woocommerce-registration-form)
But this solution implies that you must also have it on the checkout page, as it primarly goes through the woocommerce settings. How do I have it only on registration page, or perhaps easier to do as the post suggests but then remove from checkout page.
Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have woocommerce 3.3.5, and i'm assuming for most recent and/or from woocommerce 3.0 update onwards the code for functions.php is

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_show_terms', '__return_false' );`

Tested and worked for me. then you can use [Add a terms and conditions checkbox in Woocommerce registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311826/add-a-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-in-woocommerce-registration-form/49312185#49312185)