# Add a age verification checkbox in Woocommerce registration form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add an age verification check box to the woocommerce registration page.

I was able to add an agree to terms conditions one, I tried to use the code and edit it, but no luck.

I added the code from the following post for the terms and conditions checkbox.

[Add a terms and conditions checkbox in Woocommerce registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311826/add-a-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-in-woocommerce-registration-form)

Anyone had any luck?

Comment: Almost works, but the check box is at the top on the first line


https://i.imgur.com/Ff1EYDj.png

Comment: hi i already change my code so you can add the checkbox in the bottom i refer to this https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3685171c52da04b711322f1c3b4c19e438bbed88/templates/myaccount/form-login.php

Answer (score 0):

first you must build an plugin and refer to [this hook](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_hook/woocommerce_register_form_start/)
and the code goes like this

```
//to add the form
function add_age_verification() {
    ?>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_age_verification" class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox"><?php _e( 'age verification', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="age_verification" id="reg_age_verification" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['age_verification'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['age_verification'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php
}
  // to validate the form
function validate_age_verification( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['age_verification'] ) && empty( $_POST['age_verification'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'age_verification_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}

 // to save the form into user meta age_verification
function age_verification_save( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['age_verification'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'age_verification', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['age_verification'] ) );
   }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_age_verification' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'validate_age_verification', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'age_verification_save' );
```